# How can i get a proper Filter function in my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, filter

I'm kind of new to Porgramming with WinForms and I want to get a proper Filter Function...

Here is what i have so far.

[Picture of my DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dzCw.png)

And now I want to filter by Cola for example.
So if you type C only Cola and Chips should pop up.

Thank you a lot for helping if you can.

Comment: It is not clear how you are filtering now and what is wrong with the results

Comment: I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this is not a question about using the Visual Studio application. Please ensure you read tag descriptions before applying them to your question so as not to misuse them.

Comment: How is your DataGridView populated? How will filtering work? (as all I see if a search button without an way to enter text or other methods to perform a filter). Should filtering be starts with or other options like contains, ends with along what about case sensitivity?

Comment: I wasn't filtering at all yet... I just had that searchbutton there for "Decoration" I guess. 
I will look up for making better questioning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do any parts of this you hven't already done:

- Add a DataSet type of file to your project. Call it some sensible name, not DataSet1
- Open it, and a design surface appears, right click it and Add.. DataTable
- Rename the table to Stock
- Right click it and Add.. Column, call it Name
- Add another column called Price (and set the datatype to be float)
- Switch to the form designer
- Open the Data Sources window (View menu, Other Windows) and drag the Stock node from the tree onto the form
- A datagridview, bindingnavigator, bindingsource and dataset appear on the form/in the bottom tray
- Add a textbox and call it searchTextBox
- Add a button and cal it searchButton
- Double click the button to add an event handler and switch to code view
- Add some code into the click handler:

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(obejct sender, EventArgs e){
      if(string.IsNullorWhiteSpace(searchTextBox.Text))
        stockBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
      else
        stockBindingSource.Filter = "[Name] LIKE '" + searchTextBox.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
    }
```

- Add some code into the constructor:

```
    somesensiblenameDataset.Stock.AddStockRow("Cola", 2.2);
    somesensiblenameDataset.Stock.AddStockRow("Fanta", 2.2);
    somesensiblenameDataset.Stock.AddStockRow("Ice-Tea", 3.9);
    ...
```

Run the app, type `Fanta` and click Search. Type `F*` and click Search

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!
It's a fun Project so this is absolutly fine for me and sorry for the bad question, it was my first.